# Manipulating forloop counter in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-pagination

I have a paginated Django template, where I loop through elements of a list and display them. I want a hyperlink to display at the very top of the list, and *solely on the first page, not subsequent ones.*

I'm currently enclosing that hyperlink within `{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}{% endif %}`.

However, this ouputs the hyperlink at the start of every page. How do I limit it solely to the first page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
{% if forloop.first and items.number == 1 %}{% endif %}
```

Or

```
{% if forloop.first and not items.has_previous %}
```

"items" must be replaced with paginated items you render to template

Comment: Hmm no, doesn't work. Nothing appears on the first page if I use this (or subsequent ones).

Comment: @hassanbaig items is of course just an example. You replace it with paginated context?

Comment: Edited my answer, another way of checking for first page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/) to get the paginated queryset, you can access the current page number using [`Page.number`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Page.number):

> The `1-based` page number for this page.

If you have your `object_list` in the page, you can include the hyperlink on the first page only (and outside the `for` loop):

```
{% if object_list.number == 1 %}
    your hyperlink goes here
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ page_obj.start_index|add:forloop.counter0 }}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.